# how to access dates stored inside the an indicator object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebug

i have a map application, and in the interface, there a combo box contains 5 indicators(HDI, Life Expectancy, ..,..,..). I checked the 'data' of each indicator using FireBug 1.9.2, and I found that, inside the 'data' of each indicator the name of the indicator is listed and inside it there is a list of dates something like (1960.....up to 2010) some of these dates contains data according to its corresponding indicator and some of these dates contains no data "".

What i want to do is, to check the dates of each indicator and if the date contains data or value, i want to store that date otherwise do nothing with the date.

please see the snap shots i post maybe it would give clearer perception about what i want to do.

also please see how i tried to achieve this goal, but unfortunately the result is not what i want:

```
function getYearsByIndicator(layername, indicator) {

var matchingLayers;
var vectorLayer;
var yearStore;

// get vector layer
matchingLayers = map.getLayersByName(layername);
if (matchingLayers.length == 1) {
    vectorLayer = matchingLayers[0];
}
else {
    console.log("getThematicStyleMap: Warning, the layer " + layername + " was not found!");
    return;
}

for (var i=0;i < vectorLayer.features.length;i++) {
    if (vectorLayer.features[i]['data'][indicator]) {
        // extract keys here!
    }
}

//build store containing the extracted keys

//return the store
return yearStore;
```

}

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its an object, I guess you can access it by:

```
$data->{propertyname}
```

EDIT: I was confused, I guess you are using javascript instead of PHP (which is one of your tags). When you are using javascript, you can access the values like your accessing arrays, so `variable["property"]["subproperty"]` etc

EDIT2: You can check it using

```
   if(data["HDI"][1980] != "")
   {
      //date is not empty
   }
```

EDIT3: Iterate over the content by using:

```
for(var key in data["HDI"])
{
  //Key is 1980 etc
  if(data["HDI"][key] != "")
  {
    //Date is not empty
  }
}
```

Comment: if the posted snap shots, there are (HDI,mobile cellular, life expectancy). these are the indicators and listed beneath them, there is a list of dates. i just want to know how to check if these dates contains data or not

Comment: i removed the PHP tag. would you please modify your example in terms of the variable used in my example?

Comment: great, but there is another thing, each indicator like (HDI,Life Expectancy,..) contains different number of dates. e.g: HDI might contains 7 dates and lifeexpectancy might containg 4 dates. how to get the length of them so that i can use a loop. would you please provide an example, i would highly appreciate it.